# Terraform azurerm provider tries to register with wrong credentials

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I try to run terraform with azurerm provider initialized for service principal authorization, with the following in providers.tf (with service principal that has owner access on the subscription and works in other code):

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id    = "SSSSSSSS-SSSS-SSSS-SSSS-SSSSSSSSSSSS"
  client_id          = "AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA"
  tenant_id          = "<MY_TENANT_ID>"
  client_secret      = "<MY_CLIENT_SECRET>"
}
```

However, when I run `terraform plan` or `terraform apply`, this fails reporting totally different client ID:

> Error: Error ensuring Resource Providers are registered.
> [.... some lines of useless examples ....]
> Original Error: Cannnot register providers: Microsoft.ServiceFabricMesh, Microsoft.ManagedServices, Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization. Errors were: Cannot register provider Microsoft.ServiceFabricMesh with Azure Resource Manager: resources.ProvidersClient#Register: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client 'BBBBBBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBBBBBBBBBB' with object id 'BBBBBBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBBBBBBBBBB' does not have authorization to perform action '
> Microsoft.ServiceFabricMesh/register/action' over scope '/subscriptions/SSSSSSSS-SSSS-SSSS-SSSS-SSSSSSSSSSSS' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.".

In other words, while I tell terraform to use service principal "AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA", it uses "BBBBBBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBBBBBBBBBB" instead.

It is obvious to say that nothing in my code refers a service principal with id "BBBBBBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBBBBBBBBBB".

Setting ARM_* environment variables does not have any effect on this behavior.

Any idea how could that happen?

Update: I'm on terraform 0.14.3 and azurerm 2.41. Also tried azurerm 2.32 - it behaves the same.

Comment: Terraform version? Provider version?

Comment: Could you show full contents about your terraform template? From the error, it looks like `Cannot register provider Microsoft.ServiceFabricMesh with Azure Resource Manager: resources.ProvidersClient`. You may refer to [Resolve errors for resource provider registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/error-register-resource-provider). Also, I suggest recreating a new sp, then can this issue be reproduced?

Comment: authentication precedence, perhaps?

Comment: Nancy, thank you for pointing me to resource provider registration doc. Here we can see that terraform tried to register providers using wrong SPN, and failed. Once I registered them manually in Azure Portal, wrong SPN is just reported a step later. So missed providers are not an issue, wrong SPN is.

Comment: Maybe some environment variables which also define the service principal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this - but still do not know why incorrect service principal id was used by terraform.

Once I registered the groups manually, the issue with 'BBBBBBBB...' principal id happened once more when terraform tried to create a resource in not existing group (there was a typo in RG name). I still can't understand why terraform reported that weird service principal issue instead of missed group, but the issue has gone now.

Thanks everyone who helped me to narrow it!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can output the client id to make sure that you are using the correct service principal that has the appropriate authorization scope on the subscription and tenant you're working with.

```
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {
}

output "account_id" {
  value = data.azurerm_client_config.current.client_id
}
```

Also, If you're using service principal credentials, try re-generating your secret key or your service principal. As a workaround, you also could skip the provider registration as

```
provider "azurerm" {
  skip_provider_registration = true
}
```

At last, try to upgrade your terraform and azurerm provider for a better experience. It might be some bug in some versions, refer to [this1](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3534) and [this2](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3358).

Comment: Thank you for the idea but terraform displays this error before running any other resource or output in my case. This it is not possible to debug in this way. And this does not depend on skip_provider_registration or skip_credentials_validation. I'm on terraform 0.14.3 and azurerm 2.41 (tried 2.32 too, same result).

Comment: Is there any environment variables you set impacting this? How do you run the terraform code and authenticate with azure provider except for the SP?